# Is there a better way to query out the data replace of the double for-loop?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a data file like bellow:

```
const website_settings = {
  // 网站的设置的 menu 的数据
  website_settings_menu_data: [
    {
      "name":"网站首页设置",
      "icon":"settings",
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "网站首页",
          "icon": "settings",
          "children": [
            .....
            {
              "name": "地图导航",
              "route": "" // 跳转路径
            },
            {
              "name": "页脚导航",
              "route": "" // 跳转路径
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"网站新闻页设置",
      "icon":"settings",
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "网站新闻页设置",
          "icon": "settings",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "网站新闻页设置",
              "route": "" // 跳转路径
            }
            ......
          ]
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "name":"实体服务器页面设置",
      "icon":"settings",
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "实体服务器页面设置",
          "icon": "settings",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "实体服务器页面设置",
              "route": "" // 跳转路径
            }

          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"通知公告设置",
      "icon":"settings",
      "groups": [
        {
          "name": "公告设置",
          "icon": "settings",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "notice-settings",
              "route": "abc" // 跳转路径
            }

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

export default website_settings;
```

There is a requirement if there gives a `name`, such as `notice-settings`, I want to query out the related `route`, in the example there should be `abc` (the last one).

in my idea, I can use the double for-loop to query the `name` which is match, but I am not sure whether there is a better way to archive that, can you take a look at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build upa Map once, so then every lookup is O(1):

```
const routes = new Map;

function check(array) {
    for(const { name, groups, children, route } of array) {
      if(children) check(children);
      if(groups) check(groups);
      if(name && route) routes.set(name, route);
    }
}

check(website_settings_menu_data)
```

So now its as simple as:

```
 routes.get("notice-settings") // "abc"
```